# Get new DF from df.loc[] and select unique value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with several columns, with instruction `df.loc[df['event'] == 'enviado']` I can have reduced df with rows interested.  there is a sample of df.

```
date                event           event_id
2021-03-25 07:39:53 re-abierto      93152335132
2021-03-25 15:01:33 re-abierto      93152335132
2021-03-26 11:24:59 re-abierto      93152335132
2021-03-24 08:23:34 enviado         62249953135 
2021-03-24 08:23:34 entregado       62249953135 
2021-03-18 17:24:05 enviado         47146688526 
2021-03-18 17:24:06 entregado       47146688526 
2021-03-18 20:52:02 enviado         80242994752 
2021-03-18 20:52:02 entregado       80242994752 
2021-03-20 08:53:39 abierto         47146688526 
2021-03-20 08:55:23 re-abierto      47146688526 
2021-03-20 08:56:56 abierto         80242994752
2021-03-20 08:58:01 click           47146688526
2021-03-20 09:08:55 enviado         93152335132
2021-03-20 09:08:55 enviado         93152335132
2021-03-20 09:08:55 entregado       93152335132
2021-03-20 09:08:55 entregado       93152335132
2021-03-20 09:11:22 abierto         93152335132
2021-03-20 09:27:47 abierto         93152335132
2021-03-28 11:56:01 re-abierto      80242994752
2021-03-28 11:56:36 click           80242994752
2021-03-29 04:23:43 re-abierto      80242994752
```

after get reduced df I would like to have new df including unique value in `event_id` column.  I tried to use unique() however it is only for series, so `df.loc[df['event']=='enviado','event_id'].unique()` result in an array.

For simplicity I only set 3 columns in df, however my original df have more than 50 columns, the decided result is reduced df filtered by `event` and unique in `event_id` that have all columns and index.

```
2021-03-24 08:23:34  enviado  62249953135
2021-03-18 17:24:05  enviado  47146688526
2021-03-18 20:52:02  enviado  80242994752
2021-03-20 09:08:55  enviado  93152335132
```

thanks

Comment: hi @robert_553z8, I missed the example for decided df, it is not the only firs unique. it is df with all unique values in `event_id` and other columns. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.loc[df['event'] == 'enviado'].drop_duplicates(subset='event_id')
```

Comment: Oh, I think we posted answers at the same time :)) I'll delete mine.